# Why the $\gamma^t$ is needed here in REINFORCE: Monte-Carlo Policy-Gradient Control (episodic) for $\pi_{*}$?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient, policy-iteration

While reading PG method in Prof Sutton's RL book again, I found there is $\gamma^t$ in the last row (as shown below) in pseudo code. The book said

> The second difference between the pseudocode update and the REINFORCE update
> equation (13.8) is that the former includes a factor of $t$. This is because, as mentioned earlier, in the text we are treating the non-discounted case ($\gamma=1$) while in the boxed algorithms we are giving the algorithms for the general discounted case. All of the ideas go through in the discounted case with appropriate adjustments (including to the box on page 199) but involve additional complexity that distracts from the main ideas.

However, I still cannot figure out the exact reason. Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuitive, short version is that policy gradient methods directly try to find a policy that maximizes the agent's rewards conditioned on the starting state $S_0$ (or in general, the starting state distribution). Thus, when you are computing the returns from a state $S_t$, you add the discounting factor $\gamma^t$ to the return from that state since it is $t$ time-steps away from $S_0$.

For a full derivation, you can refer to [page 56 of the solutions manual](https://github.com/brynhayder/reinforcement_learning_an_introduction/blob/master/exercises/exercises.pdf), which also admits that the book is a bit unclear on this.